# QPlainTextEdit notify/hook when selection is about to be removed

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

I have a QPlainTextEdit, and I need to get a notification whenever it has selected text which is about to be removed (the reason being I want to backup it).

So I need to be notified when the text is about to be changed, but not changed yet (so no `textChanged()` signal as it is sent after the change). I could then check if there is a selection and back it up. Unfortunately, there isn't a `textChanging()`, only a `textChanged()` signal.

What should I hook in this case?

Comment: Look at `QTextDocument` for ideas. I didn't notice an obvious solution, but if the text isn't too large, you could simply take a clone of the document when ever it is changed, and then use [`contentsChange` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChange) to discover what code deleted and where, and fetch it from the "backup". Or you could maybe just `undo()` the change, copy the removed text, and `redo()`. I'd write an answer, but I don't know if this will actually work, so just a  comment...

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it but probably tomorrow as it's getting late in my timezone.